# Changing class on b-navbar toggle in bootstap-vue

Tags: bootstrap-vue

I have a `<b-navbar>` on my bootstrap-vue page. The navbar is transparent but when it is clicked (expanded) on mobile I want it to be solid. I plan to accomplish this by changing the colour from `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)` to `rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)` using CSS classes.

I understand from https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/navbar#comp-ref-b-navbar-toggle-events that there is something called a "Native click event object" fired when I press the toggle button. I have installed the Vue Devtools and I can see this event firing each time I press the navbar toggle button.

My question is how can I listen for this event in order to also toggle the CSS class of the navbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier for you to instead use the `v-model` on the navbar `<b-collapse>`, which is used to expand the content on mobile.

The `v-model`, will be `true` when expanded and `false` otherwise.
You can use this to conditionally toggle between classes on the navbar.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      isOpen: false
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.17.1/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.17.1/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <b-navbar toggleable="lg" type="dark" :class="[isOpen ? 'bg-dark' : 'bg-primary']">
    <b-navbar-brand href="#">NavBar</b-navbar-brand>

    <b-navbar-toggle target="nav-collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>

    <b-collapse v-model="isOpen" id="nav-collapse" is-nav>
      <b-navbar-nav>
        <b-nav-item href="#">Link 1</b-nav-item>
        <b-nav-item href="#">Link 2</b-nav-item>
        <b-nav-item href="#">Link 3</b-nav-item>
      </b-navbar-nav>
    </b-collapse>
  </b-navbar>
</div>
```